# Finding the maximum of various sum of values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with values as shown

```
Player   ||   Match     ||   Score

 A              1               72
 B              1               55
 A              2              100
 C              1               90
 B              2              175
```

I wish to obtain the player name who has scored maximum runs(sum of his scores in all the matches) in this table.

How can this be done in efficient way in mysql

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unverified:

```
select Player
from myTable 
group by Player
order by sum(score) desc
limit 1
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `order by sum(score) desc`?

Answer (score 3):

```
$query = "SELECT player,MAX(SUM(Score)) FROM table_name  GROUP BY player";
```