# Finding maximum revenue day

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table revenue with following fields

```
+----+-----------+-------------+---------------+
| id | member_id | amount_paid | datetime_paid |
+----+-----------+-------------+---------------+
```

I want to run a query to find the top 10 maximum revenue days. What would be the fastest way to achieve this? The table has a lot of data.

Regards,

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the maximum of various sum of values in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8653344/finding-the-maximum-of-various-sum-of-values-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to group the results by the day the payment was made. This can be done by selecting `DATE(datetime_paid) as payday`, then grouping by `payday`. To get the total, select `SUM(amount_paid) as total`. Finally, to get the top 10, order by `total desc` and `limit 10`.

Your final query should look like:

```
SELECT DATE(`datetime_paid`) AS `payday`, SUM(`amount_paid`) AS `total`
FROM `table_name_here`
GROUP BY `payday`
ORDER BY `total` DESC
LIMIT 10
```

You may need to change that `ORDER BY` line to `ORDER BY SUM(amount_paid) DESC`, I can't remember if field aliases are allowed in ordering.

Answer (score 4):

Try the basic query which does it:

```
SELECT DATE(`datetime_paid`) AS `Max Revenue`
    FROM `revenue`
    ORDER BY `amount_paid` DESC
    GROUP BY DATE(`datetime_paid`)
    LIMIT 10;
```

This shows you the Top 10 Max paid days. :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `datetime_paid` column is of some date or time type ([see MySQL docu](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-types.html)), the following should work.

```
SELECT SUM( `amount_paid` ) AS `amount`, DATE( `datetime_paid` ) as `date`
  FROM yourTable
  GROUP BY `date`
  ORDER BY `amount` DESC
  LIMIT 10
```